# Workflow not parsing 0:# data

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

So I'm checking if `CurrentItem:field` is empty or not, and so I put a log inside to figure out where the error was, heres what I got:

> 4/29/2013 1:53 PM Comment System Account 0;#
>   4/29/2013 1:53 PM
>   Error System Account Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input
>   lookup data into the requested type.

here's my logic:

```
If CurrentItem:field is empty
 Log CurrentItem:POC
 Set Variable:variable_field to CurrentItem:field
 Log variable_field
```

I thought that designer could figure out that `0:#` meant that a field was empty. Any suggestions or tips here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new workflow variable
2. Set CurrentItem:field value to newly created variable
3. Check newly created variable is empty
4. your next logic

This will work,

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add and or statement to your check, where you check for "not equals 0;#" too.